# Make python/junit test results persistent in the database

Tags: unit-testing, junit, jenkins, nose, nosetests

Is there a tool/plugin for python nose / jenkins / junit to store test results in persistent database?

We have thousands of tests and would like to be able to track them in one place to see history, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Have you used the `nose` with the `--with-xunit` and `--xunit-file=...` options? This will give you your test results in an xml file. You can then parse that xml file for results and history. You can run it using

`nostests --with-xunit --xunit-file=foo.baz tests/`

Comment: Yes, that's the way I use it in jenkins.

Comment: Jenkins has a plugin that will visualize all of your xunit reports [here](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/xUnit+Plugin)

Comment: Greg, is it possible to search/plot individual test history pass/fail criteria with this plugin? I'm primarily interested in data mining test results to look for patterns.

Comment: I know that it does a test breakdown so that you can view whether individual tests are passing. Beyond that is not really something relevant to this stackoverflow ticket. You can chat with me if you want to continue this discussion